# ACF gallery field pagination on post object page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a website where I have a photo album page and in that page there is a post object with all the photo albums loading in. When you click on a album it goes to the post object page and on that page I display my ACF gallery field with pagination. I think my problem is that my url is not changing when clicking on the pagination. This should be my url after clicking: http://websitename.test/page-name/post-slug/page/2/ but my page keeps getting back to my first url http://websitename.test/page-name/post-slug/. My code is actually almost working ona normal page when i click on the second pagination link, but I can't go back to page 1. Does anyone know how to solve both these problems?

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $title = get_sub_field('title');
    $button = get_sub_field('button');

    $gallery = get_sub_field('foto_galerij'); // Get our gallery
    $images = array(); // Set images array for current page
    $items_per_page  = 24; // How many items we should display on each page
    $total_items = count($gallery); // How many items we have in total
    $total_pages = ceil($total_items / $items_per_page); // How many pages we have in total
?>

<div class="container photo-gallery">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1> <?php echo $title; ?> </h1>
        <div class="gallery-container">
            <?php
                //Get current page
                if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
                }elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
                    //this is just in case some odd rewrite, but paged should work instead of page here
                    $current_page = get_query_var( 'page' );
                }else{
                    $current_page = 1;
                }

                $starting_point = (($current_page-1)*$items_per_page); // Get starting point for current page
                
                // Get elements for current page
                if($gallery){
                    $images = array_slice($gallery, $starting_point, $items_per_page);
                }
                
                $i = $starting_point;
                if($images){
                    //your gallery loop here
                    foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>" data-lightbox="photo-album">
                            <div class="photo">
                                <img src=" <?php echo $image; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    <?php 
                    }
                }
                

                // And our pagination
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                $translated = __( 'Page', 'pixplus' ); // Supply translatable string
                if ($total_pages > 1){
                    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));
                    $pagination = paginate_links(array(
                        // 'base' => get_pagenum_link() . '%#%',
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big )) ),
                        'format' => '?page=%#%',
                        'current' => $current_page,
                        'total' => $total_pages,
                        'prev_text' => '&laquo;',
                        'next_text' => '&raquo;',
                        'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
                    ));
                }
           ?>
        </div>
        <?php  if ($pagination) echo '<div class="pagination-wrapper">'.$pagination.'</div>';
        ?>
        <a class="button-terug" href="<?php echo $button['url']; ?>">
            <?php echo $button['title']; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```